# Creating Oracle User which will see only procedures headers

Tags: oracle, privileges

What I need to do is to create oracle user which will see only procedures and functions headers, without bodies.

Any idea how I can achieve that, what kind of privileges should be set?

Comment: Should the user be able to execute these procedures & functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a view with a DBA account and granting SELECT on this view should work:

```
CREATE VIEW dba_source_pkg_headers AS
SELECT *
  FROM dba_source
 WHERE type = 'PACKAGE';

GRANT select ON dba_source_pkg_headers TO your_user;
```

---

update: this would not work with unpackaged functions and procedures. I don't think you can separate header and body with regular functions/procedures.

If you use regular functions and procedures, you could grant select on `dba_arguments`, this would give you access to all function/procedure parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is even possible. As a workaround, you could create "facade" procedures in a schema that your user has access to, and then delegate the work to procedures in another schema, that your user has no access to. But that's a quite intrusive modification in your database design.

Comment: Actually I'm searching this solution for our provider. We have acces to this database and we can call procedures by DBLINK but we can't see any packages, and we came up with an idea that our provider could create for us another user which would see only the headers.